# how to remove forward slash from my string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have string like

```
var str='Dowagiac\'s Olympic wrestler recalled'
```

i want to remove (forward slash) from string.

```
var str1=str.replace(/\'/g, '\\\'');

alert(str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

No regex, but it will still do the trick.

```
str = str.split('\\').join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace "\" with "".

```
var str="Dowagiac\'s Olympic wrestler recalled";
foo = str.replace("\\","");
alert(foo);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8dS6/)